# turn away to assign a property from Class method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, cocoa

I am just curious as if there is anyway to assign a property that is being triggered from class method?

Ex:

```
+ (void)asyncResponse:(NSDictionary*)response:(NSError*)error
```

I am getting a response of `NSURLConnection` in that call, however, I am trying to use this in my another class and set that dictionary as a property, but it gives me the error as this is a class method. That asyncResponse is a "Delegate call" I am using to direct to any particular class in runtime.

Thanks.

Comment: You can do that, but on what instance do you want to change that property? All instance or just one? If one, which?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri, I want to assign to "one" property which can be self.username. Hence this way I can extract an element from that response dictionary and assign it locally. However the compiler is giving me an error in doing so. How can we do that?

Comment: A static method isn't called on a particular instance, so the keyword *self* isn't valid.

Comment: Well, to be pedantic, `self` _is_ valid in the class method scope.  It just points to the `Class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of options you may use to store the variable. Why do you need a property in class method. Class method is run when there is no role of  instance. But, of course you, could pass create an instance of the class in the class method and store the value in the object. Other way would be to create some global variables and assign the values to it such that it can be accessed through out the class.

Creating instance to store the variable into property;

```
+ (void)asyncResponse:(NSDictionary*)response:(NSError*)error{
  MyClass *me = [[MyClass alloc] init];
  me.someProperty = response;
}
```

But, I dont think you were looking for this, because it is very simple use of the class and properties.

The other thing you could do is create some static variables inside your implementation and then access those variables through your class. You could even create your own custom getter and setter for it, for more easy uses.

```
@interface MyClass:NSObject
  +(void)setResponse:(NSDictionary*)response;
  +(NSDictionary*)response;
@end

NSDictionary *globalResponse;
@implementation MyClass

+(void)setResponse:(NSDictionary*)response{
  if(response != globalResponse){
    globalResponse = response;
  }
}

+(NSDictionary*)response{
 return globalResponse;
}
```

You could set the default value for the response in initialize or load method. This makes a simple class level property.